# TailTruncation when the label meets the limit of word wrap in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, multiline

In Xamarin.Forms the TailTruncation mode for labels works fine for single lines of text.

We can also force the TailTruncation to happen at the 2nd or 3rd or Nth line, if we know in advance the lenght of the text, using a custom renderer like this one: [Depechie MultilineLabel](https://github.com/Depechie/Xamarin.MultiLineLabel) .

But what I really need is a TailTruncation that works even when I don't know in advance how many lines of text will fit in a label.

If the height of my Label changes, and so the number of lines of text that can fit in it, I want the TailTruncation happens at the end of the available space. Not at the line before and neither at the line after.

How can I get TailTruncation happens when the text meets the limit of the available word wrap space inside the Label bounds?

Is there a custom renderer trick that allows to calculate the number of lines that fit inside the bounds and set the TailTruncation line number accordingly (on both iOS and Android)?

Thanks in advance.